# Error on Wordpress Admin URL after moving from localhost to remote

Tags: php, wordpress, git, dns

I have created a WordPress project in my localhost, this is working.

I sent my project to git repository for hosting this in my `VPS`, I cloned the project in my `VPS` and imported my local database to remote database.

My Wordpress is hosting in remote, but why when I try access admin area with url `hwsystem.com.br/wp-admin`, this redirecting me to `http://localhost/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fhwsystem.com.br%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` ?

How can I fix this problem?

---

I found where the problem is!

This problem is because I import database of my local database, where `options_value` of `options_name` in `wp_options` table is `http://localhost`, I just change it to my remote domain and is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When You move your files please login to your **database** and update the ***wp_options*** table ***site url*** and ***home url*** fields to your actual location.

Then login to the back end and update all **permalinks**

All done!

Answer (score 1):

In your *`wp_options`* table in the MySQL DB, change the site url value to the remote site's domain name (i.e., hwsystem.com.br). It's most likely currently set to `localhost` You can also make this change within the admin interface, but seeing as you cannot access it, you'll need to change this value directly within the database.

Depending on your comfortability with MySQL, you can easily update this value with a SQL command, or use a GUI application such as HeidiSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Moving a Wordpress website from localhost to online is not that simple, some times there are a lot of urls you have to change instead of only dealing with `wp_options` for example images path usually include the full localhost address.

- The best and simplest way to make this right is by using this plugin: [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)
  It will make any needed change it needs to happen, check it out.
- You can also try to search and remove/replace localhost strings or anything else with this tool also https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB this works too.