# Moving WordPress site from one server to another

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with a  wordpress site on a test server. What i am supposed to do is add all the data against pages, posts and custom posts types and then put it live

Suppose right now site is here  : www.test,com/web

it has all the  pages  posts and   custom posts with proper data  .Live site is here  www.site.com  with fully functional theme but without proper data . so now  what is the best way to move my wordpress  site  from test.com/web to  www.site.com  so that  it may have all the  navs, posts , pages and custom posts as well .

Need you expert opinion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on Wordpress Admin URL after moving from localhost to remote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804325/error-on-wordpress-admin-url-after-moving-from-localhost-to-remote)

Comment: How did you get on with this? You haven't really marked any answers as helpful or not to you. It's good to finish questions that are asked here, and mark an appropriate answer, rather than just leave a question unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done relatively easily, but it's in a few parts.

Firstly, transfer all of your web files. This is best done via FTP. I'd recommend making a backup of them, and keeping them locally for now, just incase something happens. TRansfer everything from your existing public folder, into the new one.

Secondly, YOu'll need to make a backup of the existing database. Your existing web host will help with this. Usually, you login to the SQL server using PHPMyAdmin, and export the database to a SQL file. Then you do an import on your new server using the same, or similar software.

Thirdly, you'll need to update your `wp-config.php` file to reflect your new database settings.

That's it, assuming the domain name hasn't changed, and you'e switching DNS over. If you're moving to a completeley new domain, then you'll need to update the `site_url` and `home` records in the `wp_options` table to the new values after you import your database file to the new server.

There's loads of tutorials about it: http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend CDrocos's approach. the use of plugins is unnecessary, and may cause problems which can cost a lot of time. I recommend my way (as written below), this way you have full control over the process.

First you copy your everything in your public_html/www folder on test server (download all the files via fileZilla or something), connect to other server and upload all files.

second you export database from test server, if the domain name stays the same then you can just import the database and update wp-config.php file to the new database username and password.

IF the domain name changes then open the exported database from test server in notepad++/sublimeText or any other program. 
if test server domainname is for example: www.testserverdomain.com and it needs to be www.liveserverdomain.com.
Do a search for www.testserverdomain.com and replace www.liveserverdomain.com

Save exported database after the search and replace is done and then import the modified database on the new server.

If files from test server are copied to live server, if search and replace is done, if modified database is imported and if you updated your wp-config.php file with new database user & pass your website should be okay

Comment: if same db is set on live server and  all functionality is  also set as i mentioned  in my question . for e.g a  custom post type our services does  exist on live server and i've to add all the services from test to  live then what ?

Comment: i mentioned srevices just for example there are more than 5 custom types  plenty of pages / posts and a lot more but functionality is also set in live server along with database  just data needs to be imported

Comment: You can do an export with the wordpress export tool.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is by using the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/
It download all the data for you and make all the necessary changes on the upload to the new server, it works great.